# CorePlot Line Gradient with Multiple Colors

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I'm working in swift with CorePlot - is there a way to define a gradient with more than 2 colors in it?

I'm currently using `CPTGradient()` that takes a beginning and ending color, but I'd like to transition to several colors in between these. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you need? - http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_gradient.html#aa2b5799e0f20c5830dbaa64be3fb55b1

Comment: @algrid- this looks like it would work, thank you!